# Ionic Native Google Maps api

Tags: google-maps, ionic2

I am in the process of upgrading from `Ionic 2 beta` to `RC3`. Part of the upgrade requires me to use the [Ionic Native Google Maps](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-maps/) api.

I am however finding this native api very limited.

**Question 1**

For example, the old api you could tell the map to fit a particular bounds:

```
 `this.map.fitBounds(bound);`
```

I can't see how to do this with the native api.  How do I get the zoom level to fit a bound that may have multiple markers?

Any help appreciated.

**old method**

```
    let bound: google.maps.LatLngBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    let point: google.maps.LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    bound.extend(point); // can add multiple points
```

then

```
    let htmlElement: HTMLElement = document.getElementById("map");
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(htmlElement, mapOptions);
    this.map.fitBounds(bound);
```

this would set the zoom level to fit all the points in the bound.

**Question 2**

I have a listener that checks when a marker is clicked.

**old method**

```
  let that = this;
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    return new Promise(() => {
      that.deleteMarker(marker);
    });
  });
```

with the native api, you are supposed to use `this.map.one...`, however how do you specify which marker is clicked? i.e. how do you get a handle on the marker?

```
      this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).then(() => {
                // do something with marker
      });
```

**Question 3**

How do you add animation to a marker?

```
  let markerOptions: GoogleMapsMarkerOptions = {
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: location
  };

  this.map.addMarker(markerOptions)
    .then((marker: GoogleMapsMarker) => {
```

the above code, gets this error:

> ```
> [ts]
> Type '{ animation: Animation; position: GoogleMapsLatLng; }' is not assignable to type 'GoogleMapsMarkerOptions'.
>   Types of property 'animation' are incompatible.
>     Type 'Animation' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> let markerOptions: GoogleMapsMarkerOptions
> ```

**Question 4**

How do you do Geocoding with the native api, i.e. to get a positions location name.

**old method**

```
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var request = {
    latLng: latLng
  };
  geocoder.geocode(request, function (data, status) {
        let name = data[0].formatted_address;
```

How can I achieve this with the native Ionic api?

Comment: looks like cordova native sdk is limited..https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/issues/461

Comment: https://angular-maps.com/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Yes, it looks like `fitBounds` is absent. Do you know of another way to achieve the correct `zoom` level?

Comment: I havent used google maps.. but the above link looks easier to integrate compared to @types and the api docs had all your asked queries..native apps have setZoom function though

Comment: Thanks, but `setZoom` is not adequate for what I am trying to achieve. It needs to set the zoom level for all bounds. i.e. I don't know what the zoom level is. `fitBounds` used to calculate that based on all the `bounds`